# Can I inject type from one app domain into another at run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is it possible to achieve the following

at some arbitrary point of running a .NET Core WPF app to load an assembly **into separate app domain** which contains `MyType` type and use it in main app domain?

after some time I want to destroy the secondary app domain and load another assembly which also contains `MyType` and start using it in main domain?

```
// main domain
var list = new List<MyType>();

// 1st secondary domain
public class MyType 
{
    public string Value;
}

// 2st secondary domain
public class MyType 
{
    public int Value;
}
```

*The objective here is to achieve various `Value` types without restarting the app and without using `dynamic` objects to avoid boxing/unboxing*

Comment: Application domains (AppDomains) are not supported in .NET Core (or .NET5+). There is the [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) class which allows for multiple versions of the same *assembly* to be loaded within a single process if that's what you want. Did you consider using a generic type?

Comment: This is very special case. Business rule is that there wont be any static types (for DTO objects). They are constructed from metadata received from server and they can change during the app life-time

Comment: Assuming that was possible in .net core (which is not), loading and unloading app domains is probably way slower than boxing/unboxing types.

Comment: It it were possible I would need to load unload only few times a day may be a week (dont ask - I didnt create the rules). However updates are thousands a second and on the screen with binding it create massive amount of boxing unboxing.. Trust me. Massive